# What does *~ mean?

Tags: command-line, filenames, rm

At the end of a makefile I saw

```
rm -f *~ *.class
```

I understand the `*.class`, but what's `*~`?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572809/what-does-the-bash-command-rm-do

Comment: This question should be closed and one of it's duplicate's reopened instead: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76189/what-does-the-tilde-mean-at-the-end-of-a-filename Since the duplicate is more canonical (see http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2840/which-duplicate-should-be-closed).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's basically removing backup files.

`*~` means all files ending in `~`.

Many Unix/Linux systems programs create backup files that end in `~`.

For example, the `emacs` and `nano` editors automatically save a backup copy of each file you edit.  When it saves a file, the old version gets saved using the file name with a tilde (`~`) added to the end.

`Vim` will do the same if you put `:set backup` in your `.vimrc`.

`*~` on Unix/Linux is like `*.bak` on Windows.

Comment: Ah! I was overthinking it. Thought it was removing all home directories or something...

Comment: `~` only get expanded into a home directory if it appears at the start of a word.

Comment: You should be very careful if you ever publish a website to exclude those file at all cost as one of the classical way to attack a website it to search those file that will be simply diplayed by your webserver as text files, and so reveal your server code (which is bad because no code are 100% reliable)