# What does the tilde (~) mean at the end of a filename?

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, filenames, special-characters

What is the file with the `~` at the end of the filename for?

```
$ ls # aliased to add flags
-rwxrwxr-x  1 durrantm  2741 May 16 09:28 strip_out_rspec_prep_cmds.sh~*
drwxrwxr-x 13 durrantm  4096 May 16 14:21 ../
-rwxrwxr-x  1 durrantm  2221 May 16 14:58 strip_out_rspec_prep_cmds.sh*
```

This is not the same as `.swp` files which are there while editing.

The two files have quite a few differences and the newer file (**no** `~` at the end) has the most recent changes and those changes are not in the older (~) file.

Looks like I can delete it?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173151/what-does-the-tilde-at-the-end-of-a-file-name-stand-for

Comment: This is a more canonical (clear, concise, and less localized) Q&A than the duplicate therefore should be reopened to replace it.  See: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2840/which-duplicate-should-be-closed

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Typically files ending with a `~` are backups created by editors like `emacs`, `nano` or `vi`.

Comment: OP asks what ~ means, not what programs might create such files. Please elaborate on what is the purpose of such files.

Comment: Also, vim creates `.swp` files. So the answer is not clear.

Answer (score 10):

A tilde suffix is usually used for backup files. Vim and Emacs use this convention and probably many other programs, too. `.swp` files are `vim` swap files which are only present during editing of a file or in the case vim crashed.

Comment: I suspect that Sublime (the editor) is also following this convention