# Where do drafts go when mutt crashes?

Tags: mutt, crash

Sometimes a message doesn't get sent for whatever reason (e.g. a crash or shutdown). I can't find the message in the `Drafts` maildir (`/new`, `/tmp`, or `/cur`). Surely mutt must save the message somewhere that doesn't get wiped in case of an unclean shutdown?

Comment: I would not expect an application to save a draft for me unless I explicitly saved something as a draft.

Comment: @goldilocks, at least the body of the email is saved somewhere as that's what it runs your editor on.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas That may be the case here, I'm not actually a mutt user (although I think it has a TLI interface of its own, so an external editor may or may not be involved -- seems like information that should be in the question).  But in general, I don't see why the buffer content of a text application would be on disk anywhere unless it needs to be (e.g., because of size, but even that is dubious), or you (auto)saved it.

Comment: @goldilocks, a lot of programs like vim and emacs save drafts automatically. For something as important as drafting an email, I would hope the default setting is to save it.

Comment: @ReedG.Law That's why I wrote  "or you (auto)saved it".  It's usually not a mandatory feature since that would make the application useless in a readonly setting. It's also not the default w/ (e.g.) vim.  So if you *enable* such a feature, then of course there's a backup, you would probably know that, and you would know where it is.  Otherwise, there isn't one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were still editing the message, saving a backup copy is [up to your editor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6781/what-does-mean). If you've actually saved the message but haven't sent it yet, it's stored in `$TMPDIR` (or `/tmp` by default), with a `mutt-` prefix. You can check the filename in your editor while you're writing the message; mutt will keep that same file around until you've finished working with that particular message. The `Drafts` maildir is for messages you've postponed indefinitely; it copies the temporary file to there until you recall it